# Howto gather stdout, $? and $LASTEXITCODE from a script block containing any code

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I've a sequence of 'tasks' performed on a machine that are defined in powershell scriptblocks like the following (they're infact passed in as a more complex array of hashes that contain scriptblocks).

```
$Tasks = @(
  { hostname.exe },
  { Get-PowerShellFunction },
  { (GWMI Win32_OperatingSystem).Version -imatch '6.1' },
  { Get-PowerShellFunction },
  { cmd /c "smth && exit 45" }     
)
```

These tasks are invoked with `$Tasks[$i].Invoke()` but have realized I can't report on the status of a task as there appears to be no reliable way to examine and use `$?` and/or `$LASTEXITCODE` after the `.Invoke()`

I'd like to be able to do these things.

- Gather the output (stdout and stderr) from the invoked scriptblock code.
- Get the status (e.g. `$?`) of the invoked scriptblock if the code within it was powershell code as a Boolean (`$True` or `$False`).
- Get the status (e.g. `$LASTEXITCODE`) of the invoked scriptnlock if the code within it was an external command as an Int32 (0 for success, !0 for failure).
- Allow this for work for PowerShell >= 2.0.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 4):

Looking at it from the perspective of a single scriptblock:

```
$sb = { hostname.exe }
$result = @{}
$result.out = & $sb
$result.status = $?
$result.exitcode = $LASTEXITCODE
```

If you then dump `$results` out to examine the properties:

```
PS C:\> $results

Name                           Value
----                           -----
exitcode                       0
out                            POSHVM7
status                         True
```

Looping over the scriptblocks in `$tasks` you could just have an array of results that you would append to:

```
$results = @()
$Tasks | % {
  $result = @{}
  $result.out = & $_
  $result.status = $?
  $result.exitcode = $LASTEXITCODE
  $results += $result
}
```

Comment: I think while what you've showed me works - in actuality, I have something very similar to this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/8635765/742600 and I'm passing a scriptblock in to invoke - but that's where I am unable to gather the $LASTEXITCODE. I think I'll ask a new question.